Excel Pivot Add Pareto 80/20 Percentage Values
Looking for some help here.
Considering a simple pivot/power pivot with an attribute "Categories" in rows and two columns: Count of "SKU" and Sum of "Revenue".
How can you add another column with the count or percentage of SKU that contribute to 80% of the revenue in each category?
Looking for a dynamic formula/measure/field in order to make it work also when changing the row attributes to other subcategory levels.
Thanks

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/identify-top-80-revenue-with-multiple-criteria/m-p/3251117

Great solution! The only thing is once I filter, I cannot see the total SKU or total revenue anymore so I cannot have everything in one pivot. I can still easily vlookup categories results to other views that is the closest thing to what I needed thanks!
